# Create table in iptables

Tags: iptables

I want to create a custom table using iptables so that I can add my custom chains in it. But I doesn't see any option to do that. I tried to search for it but didnt found anything. Please Help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are looking for creating a *chain*, not a table.

```
   -N, --new-chain chain
          Create a new user-defined chain by the given name.  There must be no target of that name already.
```

Example (`-t filter` is implied):

```
iptables -N Services
iptables -A INPUT -j Services
iptables -A Services -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Tables can be selected with the `-t` option:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And if you are using `iptables-restore`, the above two rules can be combined to:

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:Services -
-A INPUT -j Services
-A Services -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm looking to create a different table for my custom chains. Creating a different table is not possible?

Comment: Why do you want to create a different table? To be able to group your chains? Unless you write your own kernel module, you won't be able to insert new chains. See [this picture about the packet flow](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) to understand what the different tables are used for.

Comment: Ok I didn't knew that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a table is done at the kernel level; normally there is no need to create a new one unless one is adding to the kernel's TCP/IP capabilities.

What you likely want to do is create a new chain in one of the existing tables, which is done with the `-N` flag.

Comment: "normally there is no need to..." - but custom chains make things so much neater. For example adding a custom chain to an interface.

Comment: Hi Konrad, I believe ignacio means to say “normally there is no need to make a *table*” which is true.... so, i think your comment might be misdirected...   You may want to edit it.